# Custom yticks in seaborn clustermap

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, cluster-analysis, orange

My data frame looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
    d={'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[6,7,8,9,10], 'c':[11,12,13,14,15], 'd':[16,17,18,19,20], 'e': ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd'], 'f':['a','a','a','b','b',]}
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I plotted a clustermap in Orange and got this : [image]

Since I know that Orange is based on Python I was wondering how to do this with sns.clustermap?

How to get custom yticks, to show corresponding value for f column? I only manage to plot e column as a color scale.

```
e = df.e
lut = dict(zip(e.unique(), "rbg"))
row_colors = e.map(lut)
sns.clustermap(df.iloc[:,:-2], row_colors=row_colors)
```

[image]

To rephrase: How to replace y-ticks(0,1,4,2,3) with values in column f?

Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sns.clustermap(..., yticklabels=df.f)`?

Comment: Huh that simple. Thank you. Make sure, to post it as an answer so I can upvote :D